# puppet UI showing connection error while adding class

Tags: puppet

while I add a class in puppet GUI, it showing me connection error. I checked the puppet dashboard production log, i guess it is throwing

Connecting to database specified by database.yml
Problem loading console auth middleware: cannot load such file -- console_auth_middleware
Problem with loading console: cannot load such file -- console_middleware
Problem with loading console auth: cannot load such file -- console_auth_app_middleware
Problem with loading event inspector: cannot load such file -- event_inspector_middleware
Problem with loading live management: cannot load such file -- live_management

error for this. How can i fix it.

Comment: Those file entries in the log are harmless and will be suppressed in an upcoming release of Puppet. What is the error shown in the console?

Comment: This might be helpful in troubleshooting: [Which Logs Should I Check When Things Go Wrong?](http://puppetlabs.com/blog/which-logs-should-i-check-when-things-go-wrong)